# Can I use GoDaddy and Cloudflare for 2 separate domains on a shared server?

Tags: dns, cpanel, cloudflare

The client currently has shared hosting and they have Cloudflare set up. So if you check the IP of the domain it shows the Cloudflare IP, not the shared IP address that is shown in cPanel.

They want to add a second site on the shared hosting, and use GoDaddy for the domain.

Is it possible to use the shared IP from cPanel in the GoDaddy DNS settings, or will there be a conflict with their Cloudflare set up?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to use Cloudflare for the first domain and Godaddy for the second domain? Or is the second site will use the same domain that is hosted in Cloudflare?

Comment: First domain uses Cloudflare. Second domain will use the same host, but GoDaddy for the domain. Right now I have the GoDaddy pointed to the DNS that's in cPanel, but I think I have to point it to Cloudflare instead

Comment: I see, that totally make sense and if you want to use that second domain with Cloudflare as your host that will make it easier for you to manage.